# Fill Missing Dates between two dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have temp table with following data

[image: Temp Table with customer's data]

All i want to fill missing dates between start date and end date and repeat the running balance column until new balance is not shown. Same repetition is also required for every customer. When new balance is shown it will be repeat again for next value.

Also, i want to pick max transaction date of every day.

any help?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt3mt.png]

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME, @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME, @Counter INT, @TotalDays INT

SET @Date = '2018-11-25'

SET @StartDate = CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,@Date),0), 111)
SET @EndDate = CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,datediff(month,-1,@Date),0)), 111)
SET @Counter = 0
SET @TotalDays = DAY(@EndDate)
----------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE #Customers
(
    ID BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Customer_ID BIGINT,
    Transaction_Date DATETIME,
    Serial_No INT
)

INSERT INTO #Customers
(Customer_ID, Transaction_Date, Serial_No)

SELECT tc.Customer_Id, tc.Transaction_Date, tc.Serial_No

FROM Transaction_Main AS tm
JOIN Transaction_Detail AS td
    ON td.Transaction_Date = tm.Transaction_Date 
    AND td.Transaction_No = tm.Transaction_No
JOIN Transaction_Customer AS tc
    ON tc.Transaction_Date = td.Transaction_Date
    AND tc.Transaction_No = td.Transaction_No
    AND tc.Serial_No = td.Serial_No

WHERE tm.Transaction_Status IN ('A', 'P')
AND tm.Transaction_Date BETWEEN @StartDate  AND @EndDate + ' 23:59:59'
AND td.Transaction_Date BETWEEN @StartDate  AND @EndDate + ' 23:59:59'
AND tc.Transaction_Date BETWEEN @StartDate  AND @EndDate + ' 23:59:59'
AND tc.Customer_Id = 21
AND tm.Transaction_Type <> 4
```

Comment: can you add a table structure of the output you want?

Comment: Can you add your select query?

Comment: "i want to pick max transaction date of every day"  --you can't because you have several rows with the same exact date and time.  Which amount applies for the day?  We can't guess for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `full outer join` to your select query with `Transaction_Date` on below query(below sample is with date filter):

```
create table #TempDate
(
    Customer_Id int,
    Transaction_Date datetime,
    Running_Balance varchar(50)
)

insert into #TempDate (Customer_Id, Transaction_Date, Running_Balance) values (21, '2018-11-01 13:20:37.923', '41,863.54')
insert into #TempDate (Customer_Id, Transaction_Date, Running_Balance) values (21, '2018-11-02 13:20:37.923', '16,863.54')
insert into #TempDate (Customer_Id, Transaction_Date, Running_Balance) values (21, '2018-11-23 13:20:37.923', '11,179.54')
insert into #TempDate (Customer_Id, Transaction_Date, Running_Balance) values (21, '2018-11-26 13:20:37.923', '11,164.54')
insert into #TempDate (Customer_Id, Transaction_Date, Running_Balance) values (21, '2018-11-28 13:20:37.923', '6,164.54')

DECLARE @STARTDATE nvarchar(100) = '11/01/2018'
DECLARE @ENDDATE nvarchar(100) = '11/28/2018 23:59:59'

SELECT a.Customer_Id, b.Transaction_Date, a.Running_Balance FROM 
(SELECT Customer_Id, CAST(Transaction_Date as DATE) AS Transaction_Date, 
Running_Balance from #TempDate 
WHERE Transaction_Date BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE) a

FULL OUTER JOIN

(SELECT [Transaction_Date] = DATEADD(Day,Number,@STARTDATE) 
FROM  master..spt_values 
WHERE Type='P'
AND DATEADD(day,Number,@STARTDATE) <= @ENDDATE) b 
ON a.Transaction_Date = b.Transaction_Date ORDER BY b.Transaction_Date
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also need running balance column to be repeated until new value is not shown. NULL value is not required.

Comment: You describe one table.  Then your query has references three.  I'm confused on what you want to do and what data you have to work with.